# Cloudformation Custom Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create a custom resource in cloudformation that will contain sub resources so that I can prevision application resources for high value clients.

For example. I have an application that has an `SNS::Subscription`, `SQS::Queue`, `ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`, `ElasticBeanstalk::Application` and `ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion`.

Copying this for any client I want to provision dedicated resources for is a hassle. Keeping them all up to date is a problem.

I would like to define these once, and use a custom resource to generate them with custom variables provided. Like-

```
GeneralPurpose:
  Type: COM::MyApplication
  Properties:
    QueueName: general
    InstanceType: t3.micro
    Instances: 30

AcmeClient:
  Type: COM::MyApplication
  Properties:
    QueueName: acme
    InstanceType: t5.medium
    Instances: 10
    SnsFilterValue: acme
```

These custom properties would be used in the custom resource template I defined and generate all the resources required for both the `general` and `acme` application.

If I need to change the default visibility timeout for the application queue, I can do it in one place and update all resources that used this custom resource.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a nested stacks instead of a custom resource. You can define parameterized templates to use as the nested stacks. This will be much easier to maintain.